# AngularJS Custom directive doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to to get the custom directive I created to work. The directive I created houses a table, which references a controller. I didn't include the ProjectController in my code because that part works, but once i put everything into a custom directive it stopped working. I believe the custom directive isn't getting hit. Any suggestions?

**app.js**

```
app.directive('projectInformation', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'project-information.html',
        controller: function() {
            this.products = projects
        },
        controllerAs: 'projectCtrl'
    };
});
```

**project-information.html**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    <!--TABLE HEAD-->
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Project </th>
        <th>Name </th>
        <th>Phone </th>
        <th>Company </th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <!--TABLE BODY-->
    <!--Angular; Repeats all of the content in the dTIMS project array-->
    <tr ng-repeat="product in projectCtrl.products">
        <td>{{  product.id  }}</td>
        <td>{{  product.name  }}</td>
        <td>{{  product.supervisor  }}</td>
        <td>{{  product.phone  }}</td>
        <td>{{  product.company  }}</td>
        <td>{{  product.date  }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**ReviewAndAdjust.cshtml**

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <!--GRAD CONTENT-->
    <!--first instance-->
        <project-information class="table-responsive"></project-information>
</div>

<div class="content" id="elementGrid"><!--GRAD CONTENT-->
    <!--second instance-->
    <project-information class="active content table-responsive"></project-information>
</div>
```

**LayoutPage.cshtml**

```
<html ng-app="dTIMSApp">
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body><!--ng-controller="ProjectController as projectCtrl" used to be in body tag-->
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

I've also tried using other alternatives to a custom element directive. I tried a custom attribute directive and using the ng-include directive but the div still wont be populated with the table from the html page. Also in the console log for the webpage it says 'GET http://localhost:58893/Dashboards/project-information.html 404 (Not Found)'

Comment: Can you be more specific to what does not work? What is the expected behaviour and what is the behaviour you are getting?

Comment: Is template being requested in dev tools network? You haven't provided much detail regarding troubleshooting or symptoms. What does happen?

Comment: On top of my mind, have you checked for errors in the console, perhaps wrong path to your template or something that might give a hint?

Comment: where is the `ng-controller` defined?  also, you show two instances here, were you expecting these two instances to have the same data or different data?

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: So my ng-app if defined in the head element on a master page and the ng-controller is defind in the body. So pretty much whats supposed to happen is a table is supposed to be populated automatically when the page loads, but for some reason the div is empty when the page loads. Sorry for not every piece of detail as i felt there was to much code to reference it all my apologies

Comment: @AndersRehn i just checked the console and it says 'GET http://localhost:58893/Dashboards/project-information.html 404 (Not Found)'. I assumed that meant it couldn't reach the page because it wasnt in the dashboards folder, so i moved it there but same issue.

Comment: Is the html file project-information.html in your root folder (same location where index.html is found)? Because that's where you say to angular to search for the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are restricted from using ng-include to access the "View" folder, where "project-information.html" is located, once the website is running. So you must create a folder outside of the "Views" folder, place the project-information.html page inside that folder, and have the ng-include have the new path. The code will look something like this:

```
app.directive('projectInformation', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/Scripts/includes/project-information.html',
        controller: function () {
            this.products = projects
        },
        controllerAs: 'projectCtrl'
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying the appropriate controller where "projectCtrl" comes from like so or inside the containing div in your project-information view:

```
app.directive('projectInformation', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'project-information.html',
        controller: 'yourControllerHere'
    };
});
```

Comment: Adding classes to directives is indeed possible. Imagine a css rule for an underlying `<p>`tag. `project-information.active p{//some css}`

Comment: The more you know  :) Thanks Anders I will need to look into that!

Comment: @ifTrue I looked at the console and the error its giving me is 'GET localhost:58893/Dashboards/project-information.html 404 (Not Found)'

Comment: Is project-information.html in a folder? If you can please post your updated version of your directive so I can see your changes.

Comment: @ifTrue just updated the code, added in the layoutpage code, updated the directive as well as a picture of my file routes

Comment: There are a couple other potential unrelated issues I see but I am not seeing anything that would immediately throw this error, I will glance over it some more but in the meantime have you made sure you have saved your work and that in the browser you refresh the page using ctrl+f5?

Answer (score 1):

use replace option in your directive and you can also add an 'A' to restrict so you can invoke your directive as an attribute hope this will help

```
app.directive('projectInformation', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'project-information.html'
    };
});
```